# Why does log4net work in the IDE but not on the server?

Tags: log4net

I am working in a Dynamics CRM 2011on-premises C# .Net  environment. This is the first time I have used log4net so bear with me, please...

My app.config entry for log4net is:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="EDI File Generator Log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  <!--<appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />-->
</root>
```

In the program I have coded:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

And throughout the program there are several places I call a method which executes:

```
log.Info(sMessage);
```

When I execute the code from VS 2010, the program runs and messages are logged to the log file. When I deployed the program to my own machine, the program runs but no log entries are written.

Comment: Check that there is a call to the `Configure` method in your CRM startup. Also check that the configuration file contains the entry for the CRM

Comment: Thanks for responding, Samy. Could you be more specific?  I am connecting to CRM with no issues. It is log4net that appears to be failing. I put the log.Info(String) into a Try-Catch block and no error is thrown. The line of code immediately after the log.Info line (still within the Try block) is executed, but no log entries are made.

Comment: Log4net needs to be initialized at app startup. Does your CRM let you plug in the startup method? Did you remember to transfer the log4net configuration to the CRM app.config file?

Comment: This is new to me. How do I initialize Log4Net? Since this program collects and generates messages that I want to log, and only incidentally also connects to CRM, I don't understand why I need to "plug in the startup method" in CRM.

Comment: I also have the following in the app.config:  <section name="log4net"
               type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

By adding

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

to my config file I was able to see log4net internal messages. This showed me that log4net couldn't find my app.config file. The deployed name of the config file is MyProgram.exe.config.  So I moved the Assembly declarative from the code class to AssemblyInfo.cs and removed the pointer to app.config, leaving

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]
```

This worked both in the IDE and when deployed on my machine.